# printf string literal with address operator

Tags: c, string, printf, address-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", "Hello");
    printf("%s\n", &"Hello");
    return 0;
}

Output : 
Hello
Hello
```

Can anyone explain to me why `"Hello"` and `&"Hello"` produce the same result?

Comment: There are no references in C. The unary `&` is the address-of operator.

Comment: @alkis You didn't edit the title?

Comment: Which compiler do you use, BTW?

Comment: @devnull I'm using dev-c++ as my ide on windows (just for testing) and it uses Mingw which is a port of GCC

Comment: @alkis So the compiler doesn't have any option to enable any warnings?

Comment: @devnull dev-c++ is not quite an ideal IDE but it must have some way of passing options to the compiler.

Comment: It must have, but why do you ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the string literal is treated as a `const char` array. The code is equivalent to writing this:

```
char array [] = "Hello";
printf("%s\n", array);
printf("%s\n", &array);
```

- When you pass the array name to a function expecting a pointer, the array "decays" into a pointer.
- When you pass the address of the array, you get an *array pointer*... which also points at the very same address.

This is quite confusing and I think the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) explains it well. That whole chapter about arrays and pointers should be mandatory reading for all C programmers.

---

Another thing worth of note: optimizers use something call "string pooling", which means that if the compiler encounters the same string literal twice in the souce code, it will store it at the same address. So your code actually just prints the contents of the same memory location twice. To see if string pooling is used, simply run this code:

```
printf("%p\n", "Hello");
printf("%p\n", "Hello");
```

It should print the same address twice, as long as the strings are identical. Change one of the strings, and you will get different addresses.

Comment: This is an awsome answer. Thank you.

Comment: @alkis Just make sure to read that link I posted, if you haven't already :) It is very good reading for beginners and veterans all alike.

Comment: I most certainly will. Thank you sir for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Applying `&` to "Hello" yields a pointer to that array (yes, it is an array and it doesn't decay to a pointer in this context).

It still points to **the same location**, but it **has a different type** (it has `char (*)[6]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of 6 chars). `printf` ignores the real type of the pointer and treats it as a `char *` so it "works".

---

Technically using the "wrong" object type for a `printf` specifier is undefined behavior. Turning on the warnings should point this out in modern compilers.

Comment: As in, the literal `"Hello"` decays into a pointer `char*`, but `&"Hello"` doesn't decay, it is an array pointer of the type `char(*)[6]`.

Comment: @Lundin What I meant is that in the context of applying `&`, `"Hello"` does not decay into a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is in context with `printf` 's `%s`

The base address for following are same:

`&"Hello" ==> &"Hello"[0] ==> "Hello"+0 ==> "Hello"`

Comment: Try: `printf("%s\n", "Hello"+2);` and see what I meant

Comment: I didn't downvote but I disagree with your answer. &"Hello" has type `char (*)[6]` while `&"Hello"[0]` has type `char *`. Your `==>` seems to imply they are equivalent.

Comment: @cnicutar I know, the intention was to tell any `"String"+i` behavior with `printf`'s `%s` (the base addresses)

Answer (score 0):

`"Hello"` and `&"Hello"` both return the base address of the `char` array(string).

and you are using the `%s`, which is use for the print of string variable